# pytest-mysql error: No such file or directory: 'mysqld'

Tags: python, mysql, docker, pytest

I'm running some unit tests with [pytest-mysql](https://pypi.org/project/pytest-mysql/), but getting the following error:

```
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py:1823: FileNotFoundError
FileNotFoundError: [Errno 2] No such file or directory: 'mysqld'
```

For context, I'm working on running these tests in docker for our CI pipeline, so the tests are run like this:

```
# run mysql
db_container_id=$(docker run -d -e MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=Somepass123 -p 3306:3306 mysql:5.7)

# run tests in python container
docker run -it --link ${db_container_id} -v /Users/me/project:/srv -w /srv python:3.9-buster scripts/run-tests.sh Somepass123
```

**./scripts/run-tests.sh**

```
#!/bin/bash
set -e

MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD=$1

echo "Installing system dependencies"
export DEBIAN_FRONTEND=noninteractive
apt-get update
apt-get install unixodbc-dev -y

echo "Installing project dependencies"
pip install -r requirements.txt
python setup.py develop

echo "Installing test dependencies"
cd tests

cat << EOF > pytest.ini
[pytest]
mysql_dbname = TestDB
mysql_host = db
mysql_port = 3306
mysql_user = root
mysql_passwd = ${MYSQL_ROOT_PASSWORD}
EOF

pip install -r requirements.txt

echo "Running tests"
cd ..
pytest tests
```

Full error:

```
_______ ERROR at setup of test_foo _________

request = <SubRequest 'mysql' for <Function test_foo>>

    @pytest.fixture
    def mysql_fixture(request):
        """
        Client fixture for MySQL server.
    
        #. Get config.
        #. Try to import MySQLdb package.
        #. Connect to mysql server.
        #. Create database.
        #. Use proper database.
        #. Drop database after tests.
    
        :param FixtureRequest request: fixture request object
    
        :rtype: MySQLdb.connections.Connection
        :returns: connection to database
        """
        config = get_config(request)
>       process = request.getfixturevalue(process_fixture_name)

/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest_mysql/factories/client.py:67: 
_ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ _ 
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest_mysql/factories/process.py:117: in mysql_proc_fixture
    with mysql_executor:
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/mirakuru/base.py:172: in __enter__
    return self.start()
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest_mysql/executor.py:163: in start
    implementation = self.implementation()
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/site-packages/pytest_mysql/executor.py:99: in implementation
    version_output = subprocess.check_output(
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py:424: in check_output
    return run(*popenargs, stdout=PIPE, timeout=timeout, check=True,
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py:505: in run
    with Popen(*popenargs, **kwargs) as process:
/usr/local/lib/python3.9/subprocess.py:951: in __init__
    self._execute_child(args, executable, preexec_fn, close_fds,
```

Why is pytest-mysql looking for `mysqld`? That's the mysql server executable. From my perspective, it should just be connecting to an existing mysql server as specified in `pytest.ini` and thus only need mysql client libs. I'm assuming it's something misconfigured on my end.

Comment: what’s the host you are using?

Comment: @gold_cy I tried multiple host settings. Found the issue and posted as an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

So apparently pytest-mysql requires that mysql server (mysqld) is installed on the same host (or container) where you are running pytest. The [README](https://github.com/ClearcodeHQ/pytest-mysql#how-to-use) mentions the `mysql` client fixture:

> mysql - it's a client fixture that has functional scope. After each test drops test database from MySQL ensuring repeatability.

However, you can't use the client one separately - see Github issue: [Is it possible to execute test on a already running mysql service?](https://github.com/ClearcodeHQ/pytest-mysql/issues/214).

So the "workaround" is to install mysql server on the host or container....pytest-mysql will create and teardown test databases with mysqld as needed AND connect to a running mysql instance you specify in your pytest.ini (or cli) and create and teardown test DBs there as well. Doesn't make sense to me, so assuming it's a bug that needs to be addressed per that Github issue.